# Why runtime Mutex/Block profiling is different than CPU/Trace profiling

Tags: go

Golang runtime profiler (for cpu & trace) gives us an option to decide the time of profiling. It then set the rate of profiling at start of call and reset the rate at the end of the call. So it goes like this

```
CPUProfiling() {
   StartCPUProfile() // internally calls SetCPUProfileRate(100)
   sleep(seconds)
   StopCPUProfile () // internally calls SetCPUProfileRate(0)
}
```

On the other hand for mutex and block profiling it expects us to set the rate at the start of the application and while calling profiling it just gathers the information and return.

My doubt is why mutex and block profiling have different behaviour? Here also we could have set the rate at call start and reset at call end with some sleep time.

Comment: Questions about why Go works the way it does should be directed at the maintainers. Though [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/) mention "The CPU profile ... has a special API, the StartCPUProfile and StopCPUProfile functions, because it streams output to a writer during profiling." So the surface answer is "because the implementations are different". As to why they're different, that's a question perhaps better asked on a Go mailing list than SO.

Comment: You can also just call `SetBlockProfileRate` as needed just like `SetCPUProfileRate`. Just because the most common default usage has been set for you in a handler doesn't mean you can't write your own.